This/That for things that have just been mentioned
I have a question related to the use of the determiners "this" and "that". In fact, I searched this forum, and none of the threads provided me with the answer.
There are two sentences in my CAE (C1) Student Book. In both of them I had to choose "this" or "that".
The only key answers are the following:

It was notable how many entrants mapped out the spots on their faces.
Clearly this matters a lot to a teenager.

and

Here, it seems, is a teacher who knows how to tease out and develop
innate talent. And that matters.

Could anyone please explain to me the difference between these two sentences?
A native speaker said to me that "that" does not fit in the first sentence at all, because, as he put it, "there is no distance here".
Indeed, I know that usually "this" is used for things which are close to the speaker, while "that" for ones which are more distant. However, I thought this only applies to physical objects. So, as I see it, this rule has nothing to do with the above sentences...
My grammar book doesn't go into detail either.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.
Thank you so much in advance!

I'm not sure that there is any clear reason  why this was chosen for one sentence and that for the other.

This question is very similar.

Thank you for your comment @Kate Bunting. Do you mean to say that this/that are interchangeable in both these sentences?

Thank you for your link @Stuart F. According to it, there is no precise rule stating that I should prefer one determiner to the other in my case.  All depends on the person speaking, as well as whether it is written or spoken...

Yes, pretty much so.

Not enough context to decide, really. Very poor questions.

In the first sentence, "that" would give the impression that the result of the study was interesting to teenagers rather than the spots on their own faces. The intended reading would not be at all impossible, just not dominant.
In the second, "this" would give the impression that what matters is that here we have such a teacher rather than knowing how to develop and tease out inner talent. Same note here about the intended meaning still being possible.
Can I articulate why these impressions arise in these cases? Not readily...
Do native speakers swap these around and disagree on which impressions arise? Sometimes.

There are certainly some cases where it's pretty cut-and-dry. e.g. this is wrong:

You can find more information by following that link.

But here's a classic example where no one seems to agree:

— Bertrand is going out of his way to be nice to the new girl.
— That's true. / This is true.

I'm of the camp that prefers "That's true" here, but around 2010 or so I started hearing the other option more and more (around Toronto and in media) and now they both sound valid.

The "this is true" version arose during my lifetime, and when it first started happening, it was clearly an affectation.

@TimR That's precisely how I felt about it. But I have since noticed it used this way in older works, e.g. More's trial in Robert Bolt's A Man for All Seasons. That, however, only strengthens the case for its being an affectation in our day!
